# I have the start and end address of a process running, how can i read the content in that memory region? Address got through dump analysis of memory

Tags: java, memory

I have the start and end address of a process running, how can i read the content in that memory region? Address got through dump analysis of memory. I need a program, tried many. but most of them are resulting in vague dumps

Comment: Please provide one sample of the many attempted, ideally one closest to what you would want to achieve, then shortly hint at what is missing and maybe shorten the title  of the question? Thanks.

Comment: Except for _possibly_ Java2ME, which may not have processes at all, the platforms where Java runs are virtual-memory operating systems where it is meaningless to talk about 'the' start and end address of a process; each process has multiple regions of address space, anywhere from a few to thousands, mapped to available real memory and/or swap in a fashion indistinguishable from random unless you are deeply intimate with the OS. How (and whether) you can access real memory, or another user's or process' virtual memory, varies depending on the OS, which you didn't identify.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own using [ptrace(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace), with the `PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, PTRACE_PEEKDATA, PTRACE_PEEKUSER` requests.

How to get started:

- [Playing with ptrace, Part I](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6100)
- [Playing with ptrace, Part II](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6210)

Answer (score 0):

I had seen that the adress obtained through dumps are just virtual. Its not possible to acess the memory region through programing? Really is it so8 i cant acces the region?

Comment: This is not an answer. If you want to add additional information or qualification to your question, use the 'edit' link just below the question.